# C two dimensional array smallest gets biggest instead

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to stackoverflow as am new to programming, yet am not really a 'professional and enthusiast programmer'. Enthusiast maybe but not professional...

In a part of some beginner code of mine i have a two dimensional array `diff[i][j]`, where the value is zero wherever `i==j`. I am trying to get the smallest value in each row but not the zero value...

the part of the code (under construction) that searches the smallest of the first row is:

```
i=1;
double smallest;
for ( j=1 ; j<=n ; j++ )
{ 
     smallest = diff[i][j];

     if ( j!=i && diff[i][j] < smallest ) 
         smallest = diff[i][j];
}

printf("\n %lf\n", smallest);
```

however, the result is always the biggest number not the smallest. Anyone knows why??

P.S. I'd be thankful for any suggestion or comment of dealing with stackoverflow.com and the way i asked my question, since am new here... thank you in advance...

EDIT
after the answers below, i decided to make the i=1 a special case and make two separate functions for both cases... however, when i try to assign j to other variable i failed... in the previous code:

```
if (j!=i && diff[i][j]<smallest) {smallest=diff[i][j]; d=j}
```

declared d previously and everything... when i print d it prints a random number >maybe the memory location content... tried for debugging to assign an initial value - with the declaration - and when printing it came out the initial value... the point is i want d to hold the column where the smallest value is... how can i acheive that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize smallest

```
i=1;
double smallest = diff[1][2]; // initialize it to a non-diagonal element in the column
for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
    if (j!=i && diff[i][j]<smallest){
        smallest=diff[i][j];
    }
printf("\n %lf\n", smallest);
```

EDIT:

You also seem to have `{ smallest= diff[i][j]; .. }` in your code that overrides the value of smallest each iteration.  I removed it in my answer.

Comment: @AMY: You should also check out Steve Jessop's answer below he has identified some other issues you should fix.

Comment: thank you, @GWW. i did 
    i=1;
    double smallest=diff[i][1];
    for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
          if (j!=i && diff[i][j]<smallest) {smallest=diff[i][j];}
    }
    printf("\n %lf\n", smallest);

now it led to other problem, since the value of diff[1][1] is zero, no other value will be smaller!!!

Comment: @AMY: Isn't that what you are expecting though? to find the smallest value?

Comment: yeah i noticed the removal from your answer and did it too.. i is assigned alone above because in the code it will be scanned from the user or as a result of other function (didnt decide yet)... your suggestion worked great for the first row but what it'll be like when dealing with other rows?? in the 2nd row if started with i+1 we neglect diff[2][1] which is non-zero...

Comment: @GWW: no, it's the smallest *excluding* the zero diagonal, so smallest shouldn't be initialized to `diffs[1][1]`.

Comment: Oh my mistake, perhaps you could initialize diff to diff[1][2] instead or some other non diagonal value.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I misread the diagonal part, I've updated my answer thanks.

Comment: @GWW , @Steve i decided to make the i=1 a special case and make two separate functions for both cases... however, when i try to assign j to other variable i failed...
in the previous code:
`          if (j!=i && diff[i][j]<smallest) {smallest=diff[i][j]; d=j}`
declared d previously and everything... when i print d it prints a random number >maybe the memory location content... tried for debugging to assign an initial value - with the declaration - and when printing it came out the initial value... the point is i want d to hold the column where the smallest value is... how can i acheive that??

Comment: @AMY: Can you please edit our question to elaborate? it's hard to read comments that long.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, array indexes start from 0 in C, not 1, so you should have `j = 0; j < n`, assuming `n` is the size of the array.

Then, you assign to `smallest` every time around the loop, not just if the new value is smaller. So, what you're seeing is the *last* value.

Assuming that you really do run one past the end of the row, this "last value" is probably actually the first value in the next row. Or some arbitrary value stored in the memory that just so happens to be past the end of the array, if your array has exactly 2 rows. Anyway, it's Undefined Behavior to read past the end of an array, which is Not Good. Anything is allowed to happen, and what does happen often is more puzzling than you expect.

Comment: thank you Steve,, that really helped.. do u have any suggestions for alternative algorithms??

Comment: The algorithm is basically OK, just change the way that `smallest` is initialized. Provided that you deal with the case `n=1` separately (there's no such thing as the "smallest" of an empty set), you can just do `double smallest = DBL_MAX` and be sure that, barring infinity and NaN, the first element you look at will replace it (or be equal to it which is also fine). Dealing with infinity in the array is a bit implementation-dependent, since C doesn't require infinities, but consider `INFINITY` and `HUGE_VAL`. Dealing with NaN is a pain, first decide whether to ignore it or make the result NaN

Answer (score 1):

Careful about your array indexes. In C array indexes start at zero.

For:

```
 double array[10];
```

you would go through all ten elements with:

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    printf( "The array value at %d is %g\n", i, array[i] );
```

Comment: thank you LavaSlider, i'll be correcting the entire program since i messed it up.. any other comment or suggestion on the algorithm??